# How to append a value to a variable in robot framework

Tags: testing, automation, robotframework

I have a variable ${dirname} . I want to append some value to this variable while calling one function .

```
eg: func_name ${dir_name}_something_here
```

But I do not want the variable value to be altered .How can I achieve this ?

Comment: is this failing for you in some way?  What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Just append it as you are already doing

```
${dir_name}/application/code/test
```

It will not alter the ${dir_name} variable